# Install pip package when already satisfied by distro package

Tags: python, docker, pip, apt

I have something like the following in my Dockerfile:

```
ADD api/requirements.txt /app/

# Install apt and pip packages
RUN set -ex \
    && BUILD_DEPS=" \
        build-essential \
        gcc \
        python3-dev \
        libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev \
        libpq-dev libffi-dev \
        python3 python3-pip python3-wheel python3-setuptools \
        zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    " \
    && RUN_DEPS=" \
        postgresql-client \
        nginx \
        libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev python3-dev \
        python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel \
        wireguard \
        gunicorn3 \
        curl \
        zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    " \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $BUILD_DEPS \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir --default-timeout=100000 -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false  $BUILD_DEPS \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $RUN_DEPS \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

One pypackage I have in my `requirements.txt` is `six`.  However, the debian package `python3-six` is a dependency of one of those packages in `BUILD_DEPS`.  This means that when it runs `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it skips installing `six` as it's already supplied by the distro package.

Is there a way to force that pypackage to install anyway?

Comment: There are options like [`--force-reinstall`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-force-reinstall) or [`--ignore-installed`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-I) which may do what you want? Why do you want to install a dependency that's already satisfied though?

Comment: @IainShelvington because it's only a requirement of one of the BUILD_DEPS and not one of the RUN_DEPS so the distro package isn't present in the final image.  Plus it's required for the dev environment so it's better to have it sync up with the requirements.txt instead of the distro version.

Comment: Did you try the pip options above?